# Send data to the server side according to the event, using Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to detect click and send data to the server side using nodejs. **The following code is working fine for 4-5 times, then it requires refresh.** Is there a way to solve this problem?

clientside:

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $.post('/thing', {data: 'blah'}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

serverside:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlEncoded());
app.post('/thing', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that by using socket.io